# Block a specific file in the process of "check in"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm using Visual Studio and TFS to work on a project with many contributors. We have a file containing some system settings and connection string. The settings are specific to each computer running the project.

Whenever we do "Check In" this file appears in the changed files. Do you have any way to not include these files in the process of check-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I tend to do in these situations, is using a T4 file. With a T4 you specify code in a file how the file should be generated. So the majority of the file is just text, and only the connection string section contains a switch syntax that generates a different connection string based on the current context (such as user or computer name).

See http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/how-to-use-t4-to-generate-config-files/ for a good example.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a completely different approach:

For connection strings, I would recommend that your connections string be exactly the same, something like `DeveloperServer/DeveloperInstance`.  Then on each machine you can alias that name to whatever server they need to use.  This is advantageous for two reasons; first it means that the your `.config` files won't need to be changed and will be homogeneous against all developer environments, and secondly if a single developer needs to change to a different server/instance for testing, they can do it in their own environment without affecting any other developer.

As for you `system settings` I'm not sure what those are so I can't help.